# How long for DBL_MAX - DBL_MIN to equal DBL_MIN

Tags: c++, time, duration

I left out reading in the libraries and some other stuff, but I was wondering how long the code below would take to run, I stopped it after like 15 mins because my computer thought it was a virus.

```
int main(){

double min = __DBL_MIN__;
double current = __DBL_MAX__;

while ( current > min ){

    current = current - min;
}
```

Comment: there's no `__DBL_MAX__` and `__DBL_MIN__` in C++

Answer (score 2):

Forever.
`current - min` rounds to `current`.

Floating point numbers store value with a *floating* significand.  Do not expect values with an extreme difference in exponential value to perform a subtraction exactly.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on @chux's (correct) answer:

A typical `double` will have a range of positive numbers from approximately 10<sup>-308</sup> to 10<sup>+308</sup>. But it will only have around 16 significant digits.

That means for a number near 10<sup>+308</sup>, the smallest number you can subtract that will change the value is approximately 10<sup>(308-16)</sup> = 10<sup>292</sup>.

That's only a rough approximation, but somewhere in that vicinity is a lower limit, and any number smaller than that limit can be subtracted from 10<sup>308</sup> as often as you like, and the result will remain unchanged.

Comment: Do you have any idea as to how to scale the value of min so that it always represents the smallest subtractable amount?

Comment: @brlein: You probably don't want to do that. Instead, you want to scale the Epsilon for the type. It's the smallest number you can add to 1.0 to get a number distinguishable from 1.0. Being related to 1.0 makes scaling quite a bit easier. Basically, if you want to know whether X+Y != X, you're looking for Y > X * epsilon.